# Pasar model IEnumerable y Model binding a View ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Resulta que tengo una vista donde estoy pasando un modelo que tiene una lista para mostrarla:

**VIEW**

```
@model IEnumerable<IHR.Models.MapaEmpleadoGeneral>

@foreach (var m in Model)
 {
    @m.Nombre
    //etc........
 }
```

La cual esta mostrando esto:

**MODELO**

```
public class MapaEmpleadoGeneral
    {
        public string Cedula { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellidos { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion_Area { get; set; }
    }
```

Me muestra todo correcto, resulta que quiero aplicar el ModelBinding en un form, por que la misma vista quiero aparte de mostrar tambien guardar unos datos, asi que estoy haciendo algo asi:

```
public class Empleado
    {
        //[Required]
        //public Guid Id { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        //public DateTime Creado { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Nombre es requerido")]
        //[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Logitud máxima 50")]

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requerido")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Logitud máxima 50")]
        public string Cedula { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requerido")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Logitud máxima 50")]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requerido")]
        [StringLength(70, ErrorMessage = "Logitud máxima 50")]
        public string Apellidos { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Logitud máxima 50")]
        public string Telefono { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Logitud máxima 50")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Cumple { get; set; }

        [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Logitud máxima 250")]
        public string Direccion { get; set; }

        public int? Genero { get; set; }

        public int? Area { get; set; }

        public int? Jefe { get; set; }

        
    }
```

y quiero utilizar algo asi en la vista:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Nombre,
               new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Nombre", autofocus = "autofocus" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Nombre, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

pero no puedo pasar ambos, o segun el ejemplo que sigo ambos no se jalan igual, por ejemplo, para mostrar la lista de datos debo pasar el de la lista asi:

```
@model IEnumerable<IHR.Models.MapaEmpleadoGeneral>
```

si quiero pasar el Model Binding debo pasarlo asi:

```
@model Empleados
```

Que esta mal en mi codigo y como puedo hacer que ambos pasen? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer que el modelo de la vista sea compuesto.

```
 public class ViewModel {
        public ICollection<MapaEmpleadoGeneral> Empleados {get;set;}
        public Empleado Empleado {get;set;}
    }
```

Si quieres iterar lo haces llamando la colección `Empleados` del modelo.

```
@foreach (var empleado in Model.Empleados)
{
    
}
```

Si se quiere hacer el binding con el formulario se llama la propiedad `Empleado` del modelo:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Empleado.Nombre)
```